# Error: could not find function "interpolate.fft" (R module spectral IS installed)

Tags: r, fft, interpolation

My code:

```
library(spectral)
x <- seq(0,99)
y <- sin(x/6) + 0.5*cos(x/22)
z <- interpolate.fft(y)
```

RStudio says: `Error in interpolate.fft(y) : could not find function "interpolate.fft"`

When I try to use it as `spectral::interpolate.fft(y)`, the error is

`Error: 'interpolate.fft' is not an exported object from 'namespace:spectral'`

Any help?

Comment: I'm getting the same error